# upper bound on a matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

what is the smallest upper bound for the following norm

$\|\left(\lambda\ I +A\ A^T\right)^{-1}\|<?$.

where, A is a rectangular matrix, $\lambda>0$ is a scalar. (any possible norm)

Comment: the best I could do is to show $\|\lambda \left(\lambda\ I +A\ A^T\right)^{-1}\|<\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\|R\|^2}$, which is actually useless since it is very conservative and greater than 1 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We consider $||.||_2$. Let $\sigma^2$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $AA^T$ (this is linked to the singular values of $A$). Then $||(\lambda I+AA^T)^{-1}||_2=\dfrac{1}{\lambda+\sigma^2}$.

EDIT: Let $U=(\lambda I+AA^T)^{-1}$. Since $U$ is a symmetric $\geq 0$ matrix, $||U||_2$ is its greatest eigenvalue, that is $\dfrac{1}{\lambda+\sigma^2}$. Of course, $\sigma^2$ may be zero.

Comment: you mean smaller instead of equal, right?

Comment: can you provide a reference to your solution?

Comment: @ ehsank ; no, it is an equality. cf. my edit.

Comment: can you prove it or give me a reference to the theorem? thanks

Comment: cf. spectral norm in  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm